# change the protocol in wso2 api manager 1.9 from https to http for whole store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I wanted the wso2 api store to be access from http instead of https .
is there any way that we can disable the https .??

for now what i have done , i have removed the redirect from http to https in tomcat server.xml , and while calling the add user it is adding as well as i can see when i call the login.jag to authorize the user it is making the session ...but when after calling pages like list-apis.jag , i am getting null in the session .. that means adding user / login are using https and other pages are using http , in that case session is removed when switched to http..is there any way to sort out this issue .?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxy server or http server (nginx) to front api manager and do a url redirection

Comment: Can you please let me know the proxy server related config,, i have no idea where to set this cong

Comment: https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+the+Gateway contains instructions on fronting Gateway nodes using nginx. You can create similar kind of configuration for store. You can find nginx related configs in their site http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html